# how to allow only a folder for a BRANCH on GIT

Tags: git, github, gitlab, branch

how to allow only one folder on git?

"Branch" or "user".

1). the user ("BRANCH") should not see the disallowed folders or change them.

2). it should only be able to "PUSH" to the allowed folder.

2). how can I do this, friends?

3). on github or gitlab!

Comment: This 1) is very unclear and confused about what you try to achieve, and 2) has nothing to do with how git works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would basically need one separate repository which would only hold the content of that folder.

If you need to include that folder in a bigger project, you can include the restricted repository in the bigger one as a submodule.